# Determine the least upper and the greatest lower bounds of the following sets

Tags: real-analysis

Determine the least upper and the greatest lower bounds of the following sets:

$a)$ A={${\frac{m} {n} : m,n \in N ,m<2n}$}

$b) $B={${n^{1/2} -[n^{1/2}] : n \in N}$}

my attempts :  for option a) if m= n=1  then greatest lower bound will be  1 and if m = 2n ,the the least upper bound will be 2

for option b) here greatest lower bound will be 0... that is $n^{1/2} -n^{1/2}$=0 here i don't know the what is least upper bounds

Pliz verified its  and tell me the solution

thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

a) Supremum will be 2. As choose any $\epsilon >0$ there exist a rational number such that $m-\epsilon <m/n<2$ 
And Infimum will be 0. As by Archimedean property for any $\epsilon>0$ there exist $m\in N$ such that $0<1/m<\epsilon$

b)note that $0\leq b<1$ for all $b\in B$ so Infimum is 0 as 0 is the element of B for any square number.
Now Supremum is 1(we show that to you)
Now choose $\epsilon>0$ and let $y=1-\epsilon$ and $1>y>0$ consider any integer $m$ such that $m>\frac{y^2}{2(1-y)}$ so then $y<\sqrt{m^2+2m}-m$ now note that, $\sqrt{m^2+2m}-m =\sqrt{m^2+2m}-[\sqrt{m^2+2m}]<1$

so given any $y>0$ we find a number $m'$ in $B$ such that $1-\epsilon<m'<1$ so Supremum is 1.

To understand the solution, you must know the definition of Supremum and Infimum.

Comment: thanks  a lots karambir.kd

Answer (score 0):

Consider (a). All elements of $A$ are between $0$ and $2$. Now think about limits.

Comment: h0w  zero come? as natural number doesnot contain 0 @ncmthsadist

Comment: between 0 and 2, m/n<2